# Balancing wines pH after fermentation

Tags: wine, ph

Can a wine's pH be adjusted after fermentation?

I brewed a blueberry wine and it came out horrible. The red yeast was dead, so to salvage the must I pitched champagne yeast. That was the first problem.  Secondly, the wine's ph level was too high, resulting in a humiliating weak tasting wine.

If possible, I'd like to increase the acidity of the wine in the hope of making it a little more pleasant to drink... Or should I scrap the entire batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add lactic as EZ suggests: or you can add a little citric, malic acid blended together, for a more fruity acid flavour.

Once your pH is corrected you may still fine the wine a bit thin on mouthfeel. If the is the case you can also add some black tea to the wine, allow 3 or 4 bags to stew in 500ml for 4 hours, then you can dose the wine with this. The tannins extracted from the tea help body up weak bodied coutry wines.

Answer (score 2):

You can add lactic acid to lower the pH.

Test on a small scalable volume to taste. Then do the correct dose on the batch.